# Facebook :- Post on wall issue... like_count stay 0

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is the code:-

```
 FB.init({ appId: "APP_ID", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response)
{});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) 
{});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response)
{});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
if (response.status == 'connected') {
    Ext.getCmp('facebookLoginButton').setHidden(true);
    Ext.getCmp('facebookLogoutButton').setHidden(false);
}
else {
    Ext.getCmp('facebookLoginButton').setHidden(false);
    Ext.getCmp('facebookLogoutButton').setHidden(true);
}
});

function login() {
FB.login(
            function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    Ext.msg('facebook logged-in', 'You are logged in successfully!');
                } else {
                    Ext.msg('facebook logged-in', 'Error - You are not logged');
                }
            },
            { scope: "email, publish_stream" }
            );
  }

  function logout() {
  FB.logout(function (response) {
    Ext.msg('facebook logout', 'You are logout successfully!');
  });
  }

 function getLoginStatus() {
var isLoggedIn = false;
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        isLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
        isLoggedIn = false;
    }
});
return isLoggedIn;
}

function shareLinkOnFaceBook(title, link) {
if (getLoginStatus()) {
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: link,
        picture: 'https://www.XXXXX.data.gif',
        name: title,
        caption: '',
        description: 'DEMO:-' + title
    };

    function callback(response) {
    }
    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
else {
    login();
}
```

}

(i) Missing share button on facebook wall after share the link on my wall.

(ii) When I tried to see the stat of the posted url using following query:-
[enter link description here](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27https://www.Linkshareurl.com%27)
then I got the likes_count, share_count, comment_count (even after clicked in like and put comment in the comment box)

Please can anyone suggest me where I am missing something. And if need more description then let me know.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: What's the "nativeInterface" parameter used for and why are you setting it to "CDV.FB"?

Comment: nativeInterface:CDV.FB--- Actually I am developing a iPhone apps using sencha touch and using some phonegap plugin. CDV is namespace of a "Cordova" which is a called phone gap 1.5. and FB means facebook plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLoginStatus() {
    var isLoggedIn = false;
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
           isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    });
    return isLoggedIn;
}
```

This will always return 'false' as the callback from FB.getLoginStatus() won't have completed before the return function is executed.